# Typical voltage range for a LiFePO4 BMS

Tags: battery-charging, lifepo4, bms

I'm about to hook up some LiFePO4 (32650) batteries to solar panels. I bought a couple of noname BMS boards ("HX-4S-F30A") for a 4S configuration for the batteries online, and the specification is a bit thin on details. It mentions a charging voltage of 14.8V, but there is no mention of lowest/highest input voltage the BMS can handle.

Do these kind of battery management boards typically handle voltage regulation, or do they expect to be fed with the exact voltage mentioned as the "charge voltage"?

I understand that the question is a bit broad since it is just a generic no-name board, but what is the *typical* behavior of BMS boards: can they handle a bit of input overvoltage without getting damaged, without damaging the batteries, and while still charging the batteries?

I'd like to feed the BMS directly with (up to) 20V directly from a solar panel without having to have a dedicated voltage regulator between the solar panel and the BMS, but I'm not sure if that will be a problem*?

*=for the BMS board, for the batteries, or for the fire department

Comment: They need to be fed with the charging voltage. Which should be limited < 14.8V and then cutoff completely when I falls below some threshold.. They should disconnect if it reaches 14.8V, or X (for some X) on any one cell. Rethink your 20V solar panel plan.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I guess I need to add a voltage regulator between the solar panel and the BMS to bring it down to the charging voltage.